# What element should userEvent.type(...) target to be used with MUI's DesktopDatePicker TextField?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datepicker, react-testing-library, user-event

How can I *type* into the TextField input in the MUI datepicker with react-testing-library's `user-event`? I can see there is a mask being applied

I've tried `userEvent.type(inputEl, '1')` and `userEvent.keyboard('1')`. In both cases, the input remains empty.

My current assumption is that a rerender replaces my update with the empty state of a higher order component (which makes sense, based on the application the date format mask to the input).

The [documentation example](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility) works as expected, so my issue is specific to the [MUI datepicker](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/).

A watered down version of the component (and test) can be found in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-waterfall-dib63i?file=/src/DateSelector.test.jsx).

Below is a copy of the rendered HTML to prove I'm targeting the input element with a `data-testid`, which does not work:

```html
screen.getByTestId('date-selector-text-field').outerHTML:
<input
  aria-invalid="false"
  placeholder="dd / mm / yyyy"
  readonly=""
  type="text"
  aria-readonly="true"
  aria-label="Choose date"
  data-testid="date-selector-text-field"
  class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input"
  value=""
  aria-describedby="mui-1-helper-text"
  id="mui-1"
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the following, to make sure the DatePicker is rendered for a Desktop in the test. More info on that you can find here: https://github.com/mui/material-ui-pickers/issues/2073#issuecomment-671834179

```
beforeAll(() => {
    // add window.matchMedia
    // this is necessary for the date picker to be rendered in desktop mode.
    // if this is not provided, the mobile mode is rendered, which might lead to unexpected behavior
    Object.defineProperty(window, "matchMedia", {
      writable: true,
      value: (query: any) => ({
        media: query,
        // this is the media query that @material-ui/pickers uses to determine if a device is a desktop device
        matches: query === "(pointer: fine)",
        onchange: () => null,
        addEventListener: () => null,
        removeEventListener: () => null,
        addListener: () => null,
        removeListener: () => null,
        dispatchEvent: () => false,
      }),
    });
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    delete window.matchMedia;
  });
```

In case you have a value already in the Datepicker, when calling `userEvent.type()`, add an `await userEvent.clear()` before the `await userEvent.type()`. The clear is needed, because we are simulating actual user behaviour, and you are not able to type in something, if you already have a value (which I do have in my test case).